# constant CPU usage by gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor

Tags: cpu-load, gvfs

since more than one month I see this process "gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor" using one of my cpu-cores constantly between 25 and 50 %.
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on Linux 6.2.0-35-generic, x86-64, Consumer hardware used as server and media system, CPU: Ryzen 3 4300GE, OS and some data is on an nvme-ssd (2tb 970 evo plus), data is on 3 hard drives, two of them are in a mdadm-raid and mainly sleeping, all in a self-printed pc-case, no other storage connected, two usb connected for giving power to switch and light and one usb for USV-communication and one for keyboard. Unplugging all USBs does not change cpu-usage. gvfs versions seems to be 1.48.2-0ubuntu1. I mainly run Nextcloud, Jellyfin, and Apache2, some minor apps and docker containers.
Here is a graph of the cpu-usage measured every half an hour with `ps -e -o pid,user,comm,%cpu | grep 'gvfs-udisks'`, the spike at the end was after a reboot:
[cpu-usage graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh1iu.png)

Please help me fix this.
I don't know what additional info is needed, I will just list things I've tried here:

1. I tried killing it [according to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596928) but then I was not able to access or empty my trash and it came back alive anyway so I reverted.
2. I tried stopping all my docker containers with no difference.
3. to make sure this is no virus I was looking at parent processes:

```
    richi@richihomecl:~$ sudo ps -e -o ppid,pid,user,comm,%cpu | grep 'gvfs-udisks'  
       7797    8280 richi    gvfs-udisks2-vo 31.8  
    richi@richihomecl:~$ sudo ps -q 7797 -o ppid,pid,user,comm,%cpu  
       PPID     PID USER     COMMAND         %CPU  
          1    7797 richi    systemd          2.7
```

4. 

```
    richi@richihomecl:~$ sudo lsof -p 8280
    lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
          Output information may be incomplete.
    lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
          Output information may be incomplete.
    COMMAND    PID  USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  cwd       DIR              253,0     4096 73662467 /home/richi
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  rtd       DIR              253,0     4096        2 /
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  txt       REG              253,0   187360 89142453 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0  6070224 89129711 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  DEL       REG              253,0          74451910 /home/richi/.config/dconf/user
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   204237 92540357 /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   268520 91099771 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   211448 91099041 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   149760 89141471 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.32.1
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   633536 89141817 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.11.0
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   220192 89141176 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1.1.0
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0  1296312 89141417 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.3.4
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   125152 89141633 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.9.3
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   841808 89142186 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1.4.8
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   170456 89141635 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.2.5
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   166240 89131188 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.7.2
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   940560 89131573 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   485744 89130717 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   166280 89141928 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0  2216304 89131567 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0    39024 89142907 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.44
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0    47688 89141357 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8.1.0
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   273056 89141676 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1.1.0
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   108936 89142180 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0    22736 89130058 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.7200.4
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   395424 89141926 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsecret-1.so.0.0.0
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   807936 89130244 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0.32.0
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   768072 89142042 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudisks2.so.0.0.0
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0    51272 89141519 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgudev-1.0.so.0.3.0
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0  1277712 89129107 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   387464 89130070 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.7200.4
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0  1924496 89129102 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.7200.4
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0    63552 91099033 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  mem       REG              253,0   240936 89131564 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi  DEL       REG              0,325                81 /run/user/1000/dconf/user
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    0r      CHR                1,3      0t0        5 /dev/null
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    1u     unix 0xffff8d79f5fa72c0      0t0    60407 type=STREAM
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    2u     unix 0xffff8d79f5fa72c0      0t0    60407 type=STREAM
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    3u  a_inode               0,14        0       62 [eventfd]
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    4u  a_inode               0,14        0       62 [eventfd]
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    5u     unix 0xffff8d79ff563b80      0t0    59199 type=STREAM
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    6u  a_inode               0,14        0       62 [eventfd]
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    7u     sock                0,8      0t0    59223 protocol: NETLINK
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    8u     unix 0xffff8d79b371d0c0      0t0    60994 type=STREAM
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi    9r  a_inode               0,14        0       62 inotify
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi   10r      REG               0,22        0    60410 /proc/8280/mountinfo
    gvfs-udis 8280 richi   11u  a_inode               0,14        0       62 [eventfd]
```

5. 

```
    richi@richihomecl:~$ sudo blkid
    /dev/mapper/luks-9e54f936-e7c0-4ece-ab06-89776d516967: LABEL="2tb970" UUID="2690fc02-ffbc-4092-a32d-db407eb73b7d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
    /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop29: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/mapper/WDraid: LABEL="WDraid" UUID="d905f54b-ccc2-4b29-870a-b329df2acf62" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
    /dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="9e54f936-e7c0-4ece-ab06-89776d516967" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="f305037b-35ba-4a9c-bb66-b7fdc64a7301"
    /dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="B21E-68FD" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="2ba3bf16-203e-4be0-88fd-d033f3b4d8f8"
    /dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="f8a307c1-a09b-46b8-ba2a-eec90b30dc5e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f70eb402-21a3-4f22-9834-93274ba688b5"
    /dev/loop27: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop35: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/sdb1: UUID="bd83c4b8-dcd4-4102-b3fc-70a998991db4" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="9da340fa-7116-40fd-96b4-5b15b446fa77"
    /dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop33: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop31: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/md0: UUID="b37c932a-cee9-4c00-b1c4-55d6c46c8e45" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
    /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/mapper/TOSHI1: LABEL="Toshi1" UUID="c4d5c0a1-740f-4746-b894-d066e815b5bf" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
    /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop28: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/sdc1: UUID="50bcf8e3-684f-6aa2-b325-bb179aecbe3d" UUID_SUB="777aced7-3e40-f978-54cf-badee5b17989" LABEL="richihomecl:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="6360d8c2-01"
    /dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop34: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/sda: UUID="50bcf8e3-684f-6aa2-b325-bb179aecbe3d" UUID_SUB="168752fb-a767-8fa3-31d3-b51b1d7963bb" LABEL="richihomecl:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
    /dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop32: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop30: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
```

6. 

```
    richi@richihomecl:~$ sudo lsblk
    NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
    loop0                                           7:0    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
    loop1                                           7:1    0  95,7M  1 loop  /snap/bombsquad/13
    loop2                                           7:2    0  94,5M  1 loop  /snap/bombsquad/16
    loop3                                           7:3    0   9,6M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/246
    loop4                                           7:4    0   9,9M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/248
    loop5                                           7:5    0 105,8M  1 loop  /snap/core/16091
    loop6                                           7:6    0 105,8M  1 loop  /snap/core/16202
    loop7                                           7:7    0  55,7M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2785
    loop8                                           7:8    0  55,7M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2790
    loop9                                           7:9    0  63,4M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1974
    loop10                                          7:10   0  63,5M  1 loop  /snap/core20/2015
    loop11                                          7:11   0  73,9M  1 loop  /snap/core22/858
    loop12                                          7:12   0  73,9M  1 loop  /snap/core22/864
    loop13                                          7:13   0 240,5M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/3206
    loop14                                          7:14   0 238,8M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/3252
    loop15                                          7:15   0 521,4M  1 loop  /snap/gimp/393
    loop16                                          7:16   0 520,9M  1 loop  /snap/gimp/405
    loop17                                          7:17   0 164,8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194
    loop18                                          7:18   0 164,8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
    loop19                                          7:19   0 218,4M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/90
    loop20                                          7:20   0 218,4M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
    loop21                                          7:21   0 349,7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
    loop22                                          7:22   0 349,7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
    loop23                                          7:23   0   497M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
    loop24                                          7:24   0 496,9M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/132
    loop25                                          7:25   0   140K  1 loop  /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
    loop26                                          7:26   0  81,3M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
    loop27                                          7:27   0  91,7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
    loop28                                          7:28   0  37,1M  1 loop  /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2
    loop29                                          7:29   0 126,3M  1 loop  /snap/silex-desktop/x1
    loop30                                          7:30   0  12,3M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/959
    loop31                                          7:31   0  45,9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/638
    loop32                                          7:32   0  40,9M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/20290
    loop33                                          7:33   0  40,8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/20092
    loop34                                          7:34   0 407,8M  1 loop  /snap/telegram-desktop/5113
    loop35                                          7:35   0 409,8M  1 loop  /snap/telegram-desktop/5133
    sda                                             8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
    └─md0                                           9:0    0 931,4G  0 raid1 
      └─WDraid                                    253:1    0 931,4G  0 crypt /mnt/WDraid
    sdb                                             8:16   0  12,7T  0 disk  
    └─sdb1                                          8:17   0  12,7T  0 part  
      └─TOSHI1                                    253:2    0  12,7T  0 crypt /mnt/TOSHI1
    sdc                                             8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk  
    └─sdc1                                          8:33   0 931,5G  0 part  
      └─md0                                         9:0    0 931,4G  0 raid1 
        └─WDraid                                  253:1    0 931,4G  0 crypt /mnt/WDraid
    nvme0n1                                       259:0    0   1,8T  0 disk  
    ├─nvme0n1p1                                   259:1    0   550M  0 part  /boot/efi
    ├─nvme0n1p2                                   259:2    0   768M  0 part  /boot
    └─nvme0n1p3                                   259:3    0   1,8T  0 part  
      └─luks-9e54f936-e7c0-4ece-ab06-89776d516967 253:0    0   1,8T  0 crypt /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                             /
```

7. 

```
    sudo strace -p 8280
    strace: Process 8280 attached
    restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted read ...>) = 1
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=8491, tv_nsec=751319759}) = 0
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=8491, tv_nsec=751414675}) = 0
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=0}], 2, 0) = 2 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}, {fd=10, revents=POLLERR}])
    read(3, "\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
    openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/mountinfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 12
    newfstatat(12, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
    read(12, "23 30 0:21 / /sys rw,nosuid,node"..., 1024) = 1024
    readlink("/proc", 0x7ffee7779b50, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
    readlink("/proc/self", "8280", 1023)    = 4
    readlink("/proc/8280", 0x7ffee7779b50, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
    readlink("/proc/8280/mountinfo", 0x7ffee7779b50, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
    read(12, "atime shared:10 - cgroup2 cgroup"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ev,noexec,relatime shared:21 - r"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, ",nodev,relatime shared:61 - squa"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194 ro,nod"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, ",nodev,relatime shared:95 - squa"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "190 30 7:33 / /snap/snapd/20092 "..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "pd/ns rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,rel"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "3VEVSKOLL7QYTPBFMO5A3RA:/var/lib"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ay2/l/4VBMVTNPL5OCWOA6UNNNUMKFJL"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ker/overlay2/l/ALHLFNCYV4NERBARI"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "r/lib/docker/overlay2/l/EDGWEROK"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "4e11783ebe54da55de218b0d2290b7af"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "MLZVRMRBX6BWDSQBRQ6Q2:/var/lib/d"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, " - overlay overlay rw,lowerdir=/"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "lib/docker/overlay2/c746ceabc818"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "31e13b0686a9f9d553901eac2188d6b6"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "2LAGQVHUPH:/var/lib/docker/overl"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "QAKUXGAQSYD232JRY76:/var/lib/doc"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "l/K7FU5IHM2J5C645CPDS4XXHJJQ:/va"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "overlay2/l/ROUKI7LRQI763Z3BPMCGV"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "b/docker/overlay2/l/QLHKYUYVRF5A"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "CD:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/NE"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "N3TYOH6VIVY:/var/lib/docker/over"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "y overlay rw,lowerdir=/var/lib/d"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "2/l/VIBDZDKVQLOLHQR46SBCXVX4KI:/"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "er/overlay2/l/5UTZBETHRGXRM7AQVN"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "/lib/docker/overlay2/l/GPBZL5C4Z"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "5JBU:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "7JKTPWNKCGVQA:/var/lib/docker/ov"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "3IVOXWK3OBPT6VUITEG43GU:/var/lib"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ay2/l/4NNKABRN2XMT62P6FVE5J4HZA5"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "53ea18d rw shared:2575 - nsfs ns"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/50041e2"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, " 27 0:4 net:[4026534294] /run/do"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "4793] /run/docker/netns/a6c2da44"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "W:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/CRU"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "] /run/snapd/ns/telegram-desktop"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "0:350 / /var/lib/docker/overlay2"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "cker/overlay2/l/J3RNDWQAEMTVXC4K"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "/overlay2/b5e01bdffa939fa5acc117"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/F26LND"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "d/merged rw,relatime shared:1573"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/NHF5"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "time shared:1640 - overlay overl"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "5I:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/WI"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "V7NIVEC55SI4:/var/lib/docker/ove"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "A35BKHQPZYGSONCLB2WF6W:/var/lib/"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ay2/l/IJPLWZCZR5XYDZNF4IKNTAWTIT"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "cker/overlay2/l/CRYKKZKU6WT7L6KU"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "pperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/ove"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ee35/work,nouserxattr\n9168 30 0:"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "3c0bd09dc7341ce63674c66c1167a/me"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "b/docker/overlay2/l/YPJMBJXOYQGJ"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "O2:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/F2"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "VED6AMWNQW4P:/var/lib/docker/ove"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "3425 - nsfs nsfs rw\n10486 27 0:4"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "r/lib/docker/overlay2/l/TOXUWY6H"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "E6ODRIT:/var/lib/docker/overlay2"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "G:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/EK6"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ker/overlay2/49b70ef1f3316af2657"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "/c4008157d6bfbe3d8d66cf1f2da243d"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ZP6VE3D3OWP4:/var/lib/docker/ove"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "werdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "2cfb32f3f39ce1757453b579d1991a67"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "orkdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "225b025d15896a28b03e7c02f6914b48"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1974463"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ib/docker/overlay2/a8b66aac8f67f"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "4830 27 0:4 net:[4026537242] /ru"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "b/docker/overlay2/c14d9210ebc906"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "3269c38042a5bd61ca8378bf906efbd6"..., 1024) = 1024
    read(12, "ocker/netns/1d7dc84444fc rw shar"..., 1024) = 55
    read(12, "", 1024)                      = 0
    close(12)                               = 0
    getuid()                                = 1000
    newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1400, ...}, 0) = 0
    newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/mount/utab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2449, ...}, 0) = 0
    openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/mount/utab", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 12
    newfstatat(12, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2449, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
    read(12, "SRC=/dev/loop0 TARGET=/snap/bare"..., 4096) = 2449
    read(12, "", 4096)                      = 0
    close(12)                               = 0
    getuid()                                = 1000
    newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/fstab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=958, ...}, 0) = 0
    openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/mountinfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 12
    newfstatat(12, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
    read(12, "23 30 0:21 / /sys rw,nosuid,node"..., 1024) = 1024
    REPEATING ITSELF
```

8. 

```
    richi@richihomecl:~$ dpkg -l | grep gvfs
    ||/ Name                                                        Version                                                        Architecture Description
    ii  gvfs:amd64                                                  1.48.2-0ubuntu1                                                amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - GIO module
    ii  gvfs-backends                                               1.48.2-0ubuntu1                                                amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - backends
    ii  gvfs-common                                                 1.48.2-0ubuntu1                                                all          userspace virtual filesystem - common data files
    ii  gvfs-daemons                                                1.48.2-0ubuntu1                                                amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - servers
    ii  gvfs-fuse                                                   1.48.2-0ubuntu1                                                amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - fuse server
    ii  gvfs-libs:amd64                                             1.48.2-0ubuntu1                                                amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - private libraries
```

9. 

```
    richi@richihomecl:~$ grep gvfs-udi /var/log/syslog
    Oct 30 11:02:47 richihomecl dbus-daemon[2834]: [session uid=125 pid=2834] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.9' (uid=125 pid=3135 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
    Oct 30 11:03:02 richihomecl dbus-daemon[7923]: [session uid=1000 pid=7923] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=7981 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
    Oct 30 11:03:22 richihomecl systemd[2752]: gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service: Consumed 11.545s CPU time.
```

Comment: That is expected given you have software RAID configured and encryption as it seems (both add some load on your CPU but that's why you have a CPU, to use it) ... And all I can see in your logs,strace,ps etc. output is 100% normal ... Are you facing any problem? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe tracker is to blame too. `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i org.freedesktop.Tracker | sort | uniq`